# Como disponibilizar configuração de módulos corretamente?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou criando um módulo do `Node.js` e queria disponibilizar configurações de utilização. Digamos que eu queria disponibilizar um prefixo para o `console.log` apenas como exemplo:

```
let opcoes = {};

function imprimir(texto) {
  console.log(opcoes.prefixo, texto);
}

module.exports = ({
  prefixo = 'padrao'
} = {}) => {
  opcoes = {
    prefixo
  };

  return { imprimir };
};
```

No caso a chamada do módulo acima ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
const { imprimir } = require('modulo')({ prefixo: 'prefixo' });

imprimir('teste');
```

A saída acima será a seguinte:

> prefixo teste

Porém eu gostaria que essa configuração pudesse ser feita apenas uma vez na utilização sobrescrevendo a padrão. Por exemplo, fizer a chamada acima no `modulo1` do meu sistema e a chamada abaixo no `modulo2`:

```
const { imprimir } = require('modulo')();

imprimir('teste');
```

Gostaria que o resultado fosse:

> prefixo teste

E não como (Que é o que ocorre hoje):

> undefined teste

E nem:

> padrao teste

Que é o que ocorreria com pequenas modificações.

**Contextualizando:**

Tenho um módulo que realiza a chamada pra um serviço via `HTTP`, porém algumas vezes a versão do serviço é atualizada e quero permitir que quem está consumindo o módulo possa realizar essa atualização sem precisar aguardar que eu faça a atualização do `link` da versão. Porém essa configuração só é necessária uma vez e não em toda chamada do serviço.

**Observação:** Estou utilizando o o [**Airbnb Style Guide**](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) e gostaria de continuar neste padrão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi atribuindo valores na própria variável e verificando o preenchimento na função de configuração:

```
let opcoes = {
  prefixo: 'padrao'
};

function imprimir(texto) {
  console.log(opcoes.prefixo, texto);
}

module.exports = ({
  prefixo
} = {}) => {
  opcoes = {
    prefixo: prefixo || opcoes.prefixo
  };

  return { imprimir };
};
```